# Javascript Animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a div width id: "cen", and with a height and width of 50px.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cen").animate({
        height: 500px,
        width: "500px",
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

But it's not working.

Comment: have you import the jquery libary ??

Comment: BTW Your problem is not "Not working". "Not working" means that the process execute but you can see the results. But a code throwing an exception like "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" is not just simply as "Not working". Please, keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around `500px` http://jsfiddle.net/myn9d/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#cen" ).animate({
        height:"500px",
        width:"500px",
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, it's working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cen").animate({
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px",
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your syntax height should be surroung with "500px"

it should be

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$( "#cen" ).animate({
height:"500px",
width:"500px",
}, 5000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
```

Please Checkout this demo [Demo](http://jsbin.com/rabanani/2/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( "#cen" ).animate({

        height:"500px",
        width:"500px",
    }, 5000, function() {

    });

});
```

Comment: Could you add some comments on what this does and why it solves the problem?